# How to use @Value inside @Indexed annotation in spring boot Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am configuring the mongo TTL for my entity class. This is my code

```
@Document(collection = "Test")
public class Test{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(name = "expire_at", expireAfter = "#{${mongo.data.expire.days}}")
    private Instant expireAt;
}
```

In my properties file, I have given the days

```
mongo:
    data:
        expire:
            days: 10d
```

I have tried giving `"#{${mongo.data.expire.days}}"`, `"#{@Value(mongo.data.expire.days)}"`, `"${mongo.data.expire.days}"`
But nothing is working.

Please someone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

As i may know - there is no spring way of doing this. If im not mistaken - **JPA entities are not Spring beans**, and you can`t do anything about it.

Also if im not mistaken annotation arguments should be compile-time constants.

Im pretty sure that probably there is a way of hacking it, but not sure that will be a straightforward way to understand and support later.

Also maybe think about moving that way of configuration your documents and indexes from code to a migration tool like
https://mongock.io/ or analogs.
[image]

Probably it would be much more simple to understand later, that your index configurations are described in *migration* tool